# Jekyll turning PHP inside {% raw %} into comments

Tags: php, html, ruby, jekyll

I'm trying to implement PHP into a Jekyll site to add some functionality to my site but am running into a problem with how Jekyll parses the code inside of the {% raw %} {% endraw %} tags. What Jekyll seems to do is turn the < and > surrounding the php code into comments. For example:

```
{% raw %}
    <?php echo "Hello World";?>
{% endraw %}
```

becomes :

```
<!--?php echo "Hello World";?-->
```

when the site is generated.

This is a fresh Jekyll build so I can't imagine any plugins are causing conflicts.

Has anyone else ever come across an issue like this or am I just doing something totally wrong?

Comment: according to the manual raw is the correct approach - so something else i sgoing in here

Comment: It seems as though any line after "<?" will turn into a comment as well as anything between "<?" and "?>". Using the raw tag doesn't seem to have any effect on the parsing of this prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you use Jekyll with php, but:

In markdown files {% raw %} produce a code block :

```
<pre><code>&lt;?php echo "Hello World";?&gt;</code></pre>
```

In both html and markdown files the string `<?php echo "Hello World";?>` is inserted as is. So you just have to insert you php like you usually do.

Resulting files will be `.html` so you'll have to make sure that your server will interpret them as php ones.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the file so it has `*.php` extension. Then your PHP snippet stays intact.

Answer (score 0):

It was generated as in `.md` file:

```
<div class="highlighter-rouge"><pre class="highlight"><code>&lt;?php echo "Hello World";?&gt;
</code></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: This is kind of unclear... Could you please elaborate? Thank you